# Order of methods returned by typeof(<interfacetype>).GetMethods() in c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

We read in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf(v=vs.110).aspx) that ***"The `GetMethods` method does not return methods in a particular order"***, but this is a general case for all types. I am interested in just interface types and need to enumerate interface methods in declaration order. 
I realize that the safe way to do this is to add custom attribute to each method with some sort of sequence value, and then sort reflected MethodInfos by that sequence. However, I wonder whether it is really necessary. The reason for my doubts is the existence of `[COMImport]` interfaces that we know for sure MUST have the order of the members preserved in declaration order (otherwise correct vtable mapping cannot occur)

So my question is, which of the following approaches is better to ensure declaration order when doing `typeof(interfacetype).GetMethods()`:

1. Add custom property with seqence number and then sort returned methods by that sequence value
2. Add `[ComImport]` with dummy `[Guid]` to the interface declaration in hopes that it actually makes any difference when methods are enumerated.
3. Ignore MSDN and assume that the declaration order is preserved always for interface methods (which is what seems to be the actual case, from looking at the reference sources, unless I am missing something)

In my particular case I need only methods enumerated (no other members exist in the interface), only for interfaces, and the interfaces will never have any base interface.

Comment: Have you read that? `http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2006/07/09/661091.aspx` It seems that the 3rd idea is not right always.

Comment: Yes, but it explains why getting declaration order is impossible with a mixture of different members (methods, fields, properties) AND with inheritance. In my case, there are only methods, and only one flat interface, with no parents

Comment: It is exposed for [ComImport] interfaces, Marshal.GetMethodInfoForComSlot().  CLR code is gritty.  Pretty hard to get a warranty here and non-zero odds that you are asking an XY question, implementation order is not the same as declaration order.  I haven't heard a lot of complaints about ordering by MetadataToken.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think about MetadataToken, will try it, thanks